# Wordpress filter post before displaying

Tags: wordpress, filter

Currently all posts is being listed by category,
i need to filter the list by a meta-key. I used the filter('posts_where') but all the query has been changed.
I need to add the WHERE condition in the existing sql that is being generated.

Comment: How to add a filter in a plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_filtered_post( $args, $meta, $value ){
 $posts = get_posts(  $args );
 $ids = array();
 foreach( $posts as $post ){
    $id = $post->ID;
    if( get_post_meta( $id, $meta, true ) == $value ){
       $ids[] = $id;
    }
 }
 return $ids;
}

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$IDofPost = get_filtered_post( $args, 'my-meta-key', 'the-metas-value' );

foreach( $IDofPost as $id ){
  echo get_the_title( $id );
}
```

Hope this function will help. It returns post id with the given post meta values.

Comment: on which file should i add the following code ?
currently i am working on a plugin file

Comment: you need add this code, where you are displaying the filtered post.

Comment: is there any way to add it in a plugin file ?

Comment: Apologies. I really don't know the way you have coded. But this is the way to filter with meta keys.